# How to retrieve value from config.json in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am facing issue with visual studio 2015 express addition.I have a console application and I wanted to keep some value in configuration file but with VS2015 there is no option available to add a App.config file instead of that it's giving me to add config.json file.

Now I don't have any idea how to keep and retrieve value inside the json.config.

With the previous version of VS2015, it was very simple all I need to do was to create the object of Configuration manager and call respective method.
I don't know why they removed this features from VS2015.

Please give me resolution on this.

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.NET 5 configuration is moved to json files.
You can find some info here:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/284/asp-net-5-configuration
http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/

Below constructor: 
Below example will read value "somevalue" for property "OuterKey:InnerKey" from config.json file.

Constructor for Program:

```
public void Program()
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .AddJsonFile("config.json")
       .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    var myConfiguration = configurationBuilder.Build();
    string value = myConfiguration["OuterKey:InnerKey"];
}
```

Config.json:

```
 "OuterKey": {
      "InnerKey": "somevalue"
    }
```